# What are Google's Apps Script resource constraints?

Tags: google-apps-script

I couldn't find this in the documentation. Ostensibly Google would terminate your script if it was consuming too many resources. Are there any guidelines on how to play nicely with Google's servers?

Comment: Have a look at the [Apps Script Dashboard](https://docs.google.com/a/macros/usbr.gov/dashboard) - especially under "Quota Limits." There are also rate limits that may limit the frequency of service calls in your projects.

Comment: Well @Greg, I should turn your comment into a proper answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at the  [Apps Script Dashboard](https://docs.google.com/a/macros/usbr.gov/dashboard) - especially under "Quota Limits." There are also rate limits that may limit the frequency of service calls in your projects.